# Converting multiple representations of time to minutes

Tags: java

my first post here, apologies if I have missed something fairly obvious in previous answers. I have several running times of films and albums represented in the following ways..

hh:mm:ss

hh:mm

5 hrs

5 hrs 55 mins

55 mins

555 mins.

I need a script that takes whichever one of these formats the compiler receives and turns it into a simple int representing the minutes.
Looking over previous questions on converting time to mins, I'm here so far..

```
    for(runtime != null)
    {
        //Get rid of "mins", "hrs"..
        runtime.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "");

        //Split time into parts dependent on the length of runtime.. 
        String[] parts = runtime.split(":",runtime.length());

        String hrs = parts[0];
        String mins = parts[1];
        String secs = parts[2];

        if (hrs != null)
        {
            // hrs * 60
        }
        if (secs != null)
        {
            //secs / 60
        }

        //convert all to int
        //hrs + mins + secs
    }
```

I'm fairly new to this but if I'm not mistaken, the number being split may mean in some representations of the runtime, the minutes, hours and seconds may become confused.. Really not sure where to go with this. Help would be much appreciated

Comment: Use [joda-time](http://joda.org/time), or the JDK Date/Calendar clusterfsck, if you must. Either are better than doing what you're doing, which is reinventing the wheel, that has already been invented a few times in Java and all badly.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more what's your blocker? Do you have troubles to turn the provided pseudo-code for hh:mm:ss case into real code or are you asking about how to implement other cases?

Comment: The problem, or at least what I am not understanding is, it seems simple if for instance if the format of the time was always going to be 01:33:30.. but what if instead I am provided with a time that says 1 hr 33 mins.. or just 93 mins.. I need the code to be ready to take any one of the formats as provided in the pseudo code.. If that makes sense??

Comment: Excuse my ignorance and the double post. But I suppose my real question is how do I get the code to determine which fields (hours, minutes or seconds) are provided in any one of the times I am given and then based on the representation as in the pseudo code, how do I split it into seperate integers for hours, minutes or seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have said that your runtime can be in any of the format , 
So if you time is in `5hrs:32min` then you will likely to have 
`Index out of bounds exception`

So **Assuming** you will maintain the order of  runtime in `HH : MM : SS`

```
String[] parts = runtime.split(":",runtime.length());
       int length=parts.length;
        String hrs=null,mins=null,secs=null 
 switch(length){    
     case 3:
            hrs = parts[0];
            mins = parts[1];
           secs = parts[2];
           break;
     case 2:
           // populate 1st 2
     case 1:
          // populate only 1st one
    }
```

Now time to  calculate , parsing you can do via `Integer.parseInt(hrs)` same for `mins` and `secs` .

```
int totalTimeInMinutes= (hr*60)+min+(sec%60f);
```

Comment: So in the Case 2 I would do say mins = parts[0]  and secs = parts[1]?? if for instance those were the only 2 fields provided??

Comment: Yes and secs=part[1] !!! just consider the **Assuming** part else it will going to cause serious consequences

Comment: Okay I see.. I also just noticed that in your example you actually did include it as '5hrs:32mins'.. problem comes in like you say assuming the format maintains hh:mm:ss.. what if I get '5hrs 32mins' not seperated by a colon??

Comment: @vessel , You have to compromise on 1 factor atleast , either you get the time with any particular delimeter ( `:` or `;` or `space`) else wise prefer any Standard Java Date Class , or 3r party library such as Joda ,LocalTime of Java 8 etc

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert time in minutes, you should do it like,

```
int hr, sec;

if (hrs != null)
{
    hr = hrs * 60
}
if (secs != null)
{
    sec = (secs % 60) * 0.01;
}

//convert all to float
int time = hr + mins + sec;
```

This will convert 2hrs 20mins 20secs into `140.20` mins

Comment: `int sec = (int)(secs / 60);` this is always 0 assuming `secs < 60`

Answer (score 0):

Using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), as I suggested in my comment, your code would be:

```
long numberOfMinutes = new Duration(new DateTime(date1), new DateTime(date2)).getStandardMinutes();
```

Comment: Your link to Joda-Time points to Page-Not-Found. Plus you misunderstood the question. Miserable answer.

Comment: Instead of whinging about it, @SurprisedCoconut, why didn't you just fix it?